# Authenticate using OpenID from a Node.js client

Tags: node.js, openid

I'm trying to write a Node application that leverages one of the Eclipse Orion APIs. Orion by default supports form-based authentication and OpenID. So, my question is, how do I authenticate with a server process from a node client application using OpenID?

I can find a whole bunch of OpenID implementations for a node-based server, but I have not found one that indicates it can used to allow a node client application to authenticate against an OpenID secured server API.

Comment: Hi, Would be great if you could provide more details, such as a sample of your code which provides further detail on what you are finding does not work.

Comment: are you talking about command line openid client?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a command line node application that needs to be able to do form-based auth (OpenID is also supported) with a remote server.

Comment: I'm not finding something that doesn't work, I'm trying to get started - I have no code yet.